# Error when I try run PHPUnit from PhpStorm

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, phpstorm, composer-php

I have little problem when I'm trying to run PHPUnit test in IDE PhpStorm.

I use composer file which looks:

```
{
    "require": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.19"
    }
}
```

Now when I run test I recive exception:
`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PHPUnit_Framework_Exception' with message 'Class "PHPUnit_Extensions_RepeatedTest" does not extend PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase.'`

What is wrong? When I included pear installed version test working OK.

//**EDIT**
Sample test class:

```
 class ReaderTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
    {
        /**
         * @test
         */
        public function shouldGetReadedValue ()
        {
            $this->assertTrue(true);
        }
    }
```

//**EDIT2**
Trace:

```
/usr/bin/php /tmp/ide-phpunit.php --no-configuration /path/to/my/project
Testing started at 14:53 ...
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PHPUnit_Framework_Exception' with message 'Class "PHPUnit_Extensions_RepeatedTest" does not extend PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase.' in /path/to/my/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:183
Stack trace:
#0 /path/to/my/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php(315): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->__construct(Object(ReflectionClass))
#1 /path/to/my/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php(389): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestSuite(Object(ReflectionClass))
#2 /path/to/my/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php(416): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestFile('/var/www/php-sh...')
#3 /path/to/my/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php(96): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestFiles(Array)
#4 /path/to/my/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php(150): PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest('/var/www/php-sh...', '', A in /path/to/my/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php on line 183

Process finished with exit code 255
```

Comment: Can you show your unit test? Does your test class extend PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase?

Comment: I edit my question, and add sample test class. I have few test classes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found solution about this problem.

In Edit configurations in directory I set path to my tests catalog (`/path/to/my/project/tests`), after this tests are running properly.

Comment: It's important to notice that the path has to be set via:

`Run > Edit Configuration > PhpUnit`

There, the `Directory` can be set.

You do not(!) find this under `File > Settings` in PhpStorm.

Answer (score 6):

This is what worked for me, thanks to Piotr's answer above, but I'm providing with a bit more exact detail here all the steps I had to do:

Steps to make it work (test in PHPStorm 8.0.1):

**1) In** `Preferences > PHP > PHPUnit` **make sure that nothing is set for Default configuration file or default bootstrap file.**

**2) Make a custom PHPUnit Configuration via** `Run > Edit Configurations >` **in the** `Command Line` **subsection, and be sure to:**

**a) set** `Custom working directory:` **to be** `/absolute/path/to/vendor`.

**b) check "Use alternative configuration file:" and set it to**  `/absolute/path/to/vendor/your_app/(sub_app_if_applicable)/phpunit.xml.dist`

Then you can run any test class in the suite by specifying the class and file, or just check "Defined in the configuration file" to run all of them according to the config.

Answer (score 5):

I have same problem when using composer.

The solution is to put your test file in its own directory. Here is my working phpunit, i put all my test in `test` directory.

```
<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php" 
    colors="true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
    stopOnFailure="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Test Suite">
            <directory>test</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Hope it solves if anyone have same problem.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside the PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite, this code [exists in the constructor](http://drupalcode.org/sandbox/johnalbin/1074382.git/blob/60d523d898487ca29b72dc372c56fa122c91143e:/core/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php#l183):

```
if (!$theClass->isSubclassOf('PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase')) {
   throw new PHPUnit_Framework_Exception(
      'Class "' . $theClass->name . '" does not extend PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase.'
   );
}
```

I see in your **example** that you are extending `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` but the error suggests you are using `PHPUnit_Extensions_RepeatedTest` which extends `PHPUnit_Extensions_TestDecorator` which ultimately extends `PHPUnit_Framework_Assert`

```
PHPUnit_Framework_Assert
   |
   --PHPUnit_Extensions_TestDecorator
      |
      --PHPUnit_Extensions_RepeatedTest
```

Double check your tests because the error suggests you are attempting to run a TestSuite using a test extending `PHPUnit_Extensions_RepeatedTest`. Were you instead trying to extend PHUnit using Test Decorators?

http://docs.tadiavo.com/phpunit/www.phpunit.de/pocket_guide/3.1/en/extending-phpunit.html

That is all the advice I can currently offer without seeing your actual tests and how you are running them.

Comment: OK, but why when I run test from console everything is OK? I'm quite sure that my test is good. 

When I'm using PHPUnit as including external library and set appropriate configuration in PhpStorm works fine.

Comment: Your question stated that it doesn't work in PHPStorm. Perhaps you had the IDE configured incorrectly and now it works?

Comment: I was configure IDE like in manual. I add dependency successfully then I set custom loader to `vendor/autoload.php`. That's all what I did.